# what is the best practice to create in-app(client side) communication between services?

Tags: android, microservices, software-design

I would like to separate My app ( client side ) to two different independent services.

1. The main app ( run the user views and a bit of functionality ) - written in Java
2. "back-end" ( encrypt and upload to the cloud ). -  what i want to start writing.

My wish is to create a communication channel between the 2 services.

1. Main app will collect data  from the user.
2. the data will be transfer by *inner protocol communication* to the second service.
3. the second service encrypt the data and upload to the cloud.

Both services locates in the client side

What is the best practice ( if it possible ) to create the desire architect?

what is the prefer communication protocol?

will appreciate any link/advice

Comment: forget all these buzzwords for a minute, they make no sense. Just explain in simple terms what you want to do

Comment: I want to create 2 different services that will communicate on the client side. I know that I can create 2 classes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem you're facing is exactly, but I get that you want to divide concerns. I'd suggest having two packages, one that controls the UI and one that handles API requests. When you want to send a request, you just call a method in the API class you created and pass your data as a parameter.

Concerning the API, I'd suggest working with the [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) library. It does most of the heavy lifting for you, and It's easy to implement.

Other than that, make sure you know when to use the term "Service" in relation to Android.

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background, and it doesn't provide a user interface. Another application component can start a service, and it continues to run in the background even if the user switches to another application.<

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Comment: but what if I want to create to microservices that will communicate with each other?

Comment: @helpper that's not a thing on android. Just another buzzword